# SQL query to take numerical value from a varchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a column called Barname which contains a text name of all projects.

All the projects have a number before the name with a full stop between number and text.

e.g

```
1.Project name one
2.Project name two
20.Project name twenty
50.Project name fifty
```

I need to create a new column to allow me to sort on a numeric value so what I need is a command to take the numeric value from the name and ignore the full stop and the text.

So my new colum would have (based on above examples)

```
1
2
20
50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this expression (in SQL, not SSRS):

```
CAST(LEFT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn) - 1) AS int)
```

Edit, not all rows have dots

```
CASE
   WHEN CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn) > 0 THEN
             CAST(LEFT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn) - 1) AS int)
   -- ELSE nothing, just let it be NULL because we can't apply the require logic
END
```

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @SQL_Surfer: that means you have a row without a `.` in it

Comment: Thanksm attempting to produce a ,CASE statement to remedy this

Comment: (Case WHEN barname LIKE '%.%' AND barname LIKE '%[0-9]%'  THEN (CAST(LEFT(barname, CHARINDEX('.', barname) - 1) AS int))
      
   WHEN barname LIKE '%.%'
        AND barname NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'        
         THEN 0     
      
      ELSE 0 END)

Comment: Alternatively your initial expression could be amended like this: `CAST(LEFT(MyColumn, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', MyColumn), 0) - 1) AS int)` (optionally with `ISNULL()` applied to the overall result).

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ALTER t ADD COLUMN id INT

UPDATE t
SET id = SUBSTRING(column1, 1, CHARINDEX('.', column1) - 1)
```

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example:

```
declare @test varchar(30)
select @test = '12.Project name one'

declare @res int

-- the command that you need is this
select @res = convert(int, substring(@test, 1, charindex('.', @test) - 1))


select @res
```

Comment: FYI, substring is 1 based in SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode('.', $string) to create an array, then take the first element of the array

Comment: Maybe in php you can, not in SQL though.